# How can I format a date in the Select property of an EntityDataSource

Tags: linq, entitydatasource

Fairly straight forward... I have an EntityDataSource where, in the Select property I'm pulling a variety of fields.  One of which is a Date that I would like to have returned in the "MM/dd/yyyy" format.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In the meantime I have solved it this way:
cast(Month(it.[Date_Submitted]) as System.String) + '/' + cast(Day(it.[Date_Submitted]) as System.String) + '/' + cast(Year(it.[Date_Submitted]) as System.String)

I would certainly HOPE there's a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .ToString(Format Here)

```
DateTime time = EDS.Field;
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(MM/dd/yyyy));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine with me:

```
cast(it.[interview_start_date] as System.String)
```